# typescript : How to exclude key of an parent class

Tags: typescript, generics

I need to create a generic function that takes a property of a class (Genial in the example) and its type as arguments.
The class extends another class (BaseClass in the example).

I want the function to take only the "extended properties" of the extended class, but not accept the properties of the base class.
Here is what I tried to do ([TS PLAYGROUND HERE])[1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwEIpAYWq%20A3gFDynwAOArgEYQCWY8AFigJLABc1A9txCFAB28EmWQAXKOIbwA5iHEA5buKZ1BsgBQBKDgDdudYCIC%20IoknwBxEILpQI8EAA9xt4GkzIceNMTIUNPSM5DDc5CAw4gCeAEwcgpQAttSR8AC88AAMoqRg3IISMJRg4twwOv4BYpQRFdq58GakRCZEFr7wNoKRDLgoyAA8ACpOru6eWP2oAHyEjdRTvgDSINEAgnAAInTI5NDRIMCDy2Nugh7wANZr3ABm8MMzmjfRHMsANPB6DpQgHMMANrLAC62nm1TI%20UKfBAADoINwtARAa8QfAON9fiATA1IaQ2o0APRE8QwOhHeCqXbwaiUcTwACiMDCMEayh6AHk7tNkKtoiczhNrrcHoznJBKKARl8vD4BjNnq93l8fhA-gDgWCIfjochYQikZoUWiMVj1Ti8fjCa12nqGeoJEIwAhMj0AO5dWy9MC8wbdewQZ4Ne2IcpwUoZeCOySCF1wxbeXn8zYgHZ7A5HTQAIlC4UiMVi2a%20ABYQwUJPBkExuJQIMBBCpUuRuKg6LRXdHCrH44n5agU9tdvsoIdgDmWMh2MX4HcHN5wST4IMALSseDAAoM91CBnUtBlWkIFttjvtIhAA)

Basically in this example, I don't want `hasId` to be a valid parameter for the function.
I tried to use the "Exclude" utility type but it failed with error Type `'K' cannot be used to index type 'T'.(2536)`.

Thks for your help

```
declare class BaseClass {
    public hasId:boolean 
    static getNothing():void 
} 

class Genial extends BaseClass {
    public property2:number = 0
    constructor(){
        super()
    }   
}

class GenericClass<T extends BaseClass> {
    myFunction<K extends keyof T>(key:K, value:T[K]) {
        console.log({[key] : value})
        }

    //tried this but Error
    ItriedThisButError<K extends keyof Exclude<T, BaseClass>>(key:K, value:T[K]) {
        console.log({[key] : value})
        }
}

const instance = new GenericClass<Genial>()
const correct = instance.myFunction("property2", 4)
const shouldnotbepossible = instance.myFunction("hasId", false) // <-I dont want this to be possible
```

Comment: Using `Omit` instead of `Exclude` should work, does this work for you? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwEIpAYWq+A3gFDynwAOArgEYQCWY8AFigJLABc1A9txCFAB28EmWQAXKOIbwA5iHEA5buKZ1BsgBQBKDgDdudYCIC+IoknwBxEILpQI8EAA9xt4GkzIceNMTIUNPSM5DDc5CAw4gCeAEwcgpQAttSR8AC88AAMoqRg3IISMJRg4twwOv4BYpQRFdq58GakRCZEFr7wNoKRDLgoyAA8ACpOru6eWP2oAHyE7QFJ0QBilIKldAWDANJjboIe8ADWINHcAGbwAPJJdOIjADTHpxcYU74zM5on0RzbT3oHJQQBxhgBtbYAXW082qZHyhT4IAAdBBuFoCGCfpD4Bx4ICIMCTA0Am02hYChJ4OoJEIwAhMj0AO5dWy9MDTIbdewQL4NBFUqAZamFSTrFFLVbraQFTQAIlC4UiMVicqeABZ+ZTxPBqMKaWL6cjJWsNrK5SxkOw1fBzg5vNogA

Comment: That OK. Thks a lot !